# Create a 1-1 Entity Framework relationship between two entities based on multiple fields using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3, .Net Framework 4.5.1

Is it possible to create a 1-1 Entity Framework relationship between two entities based on multiple fields using Data Annotations?

In the example below, I want to be able to include Dog.Dogform when Dog is loaded.  The two are related on OwnerId + DogTypeId.  DogForm contains a unique index on OwnerId + DogTypeId, so there is always 1 or zero DogForms for every Dog.

```
public class Dog
{
    [Key]
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public virtual DogForm DogForm { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public int DogTypeId { get; set; }
}
public class DogForm
{
    [Key]
    public int DogFormId { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public int DogTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

The obvious answer here is to add "DogFormId" to the "Dog" table and create a foreign key relationship, but I'm dealing with a legacy database that for multiple reasons cannot be altered.

If this is not possible using Data Annotations, is it possible using Fluent Api?

Comment: Relationships in EF6 should always be between FK and PK. References to unique indexes are not supported, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do it with DataAnnotations, but it's pretty easy with the Fluent API. The below should work. I'm coding from memory, so it may need a tweak or two.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().HasOptional(a => a.DogForm).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(a => new { a.OwnerId, a.DogTypeId });
```

If you add a navigation property to `DogForm` just change `WithRequired()` to `WithRequired(a => a.Dog)`

Comment: @Nathan_Ruff, what do you mean by "add a navigation property to Dogform..."?

Comment: Adding `public virtual Dog Dog { get; set; }` to your `DogForm`. It's a navigation property back to it's parent class. It helps if you may need to look up a `DogForm` by it's ID and see what `Dog` it's attached to.

Comment: WithRequired() does not expose HasForeignKey(), but WithMany() does.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer does not work.  There seems to be no way to do what I want to do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You can use a mix of DataAnnotations and Fluent API to accomplish this. Try updating your `DogForm` class with the `public virtual Dog Dog { get; set; }` navigation property. Then add `[ForeignKey("OwnerId,DogTypeId")]` DataAnnotation to that navigation property. That will tell the Fluent API what foreign keys to use. Then use the Fluent API to map the navigation properties with `modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().HasOptional(a => a.DogForm).WithRequired(a => a.Dog)`